# How to decode GUID in AlbumData.xml (iPhoto)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, iphoto

I tried to parse AlbumData.xml and found strange GUID string value, how to convert it to integer value ?
eg : f7hWRm%xSMiYVfEynRpo7g = 4.29497e+09

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You simply don't. It's an NSString.

A suggestion is to change the extension to .plist and open in Xcode. You can then see the data types.

Sort of a related thing, iTunes sends a NSDistributedNotificationCenter note whenever its library changes. Does iPhoto do something similar for its AlbumData.xml? I didn't know if I should post this as a new question since it is somewhat relevant to this one.